# How can I render only part of topojson file at certain zoom level in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am making a map of parcels in Boston, which I draw using D3 onto a Leaflet basemap. Within the topojson file there is information for each parcel (city councilor, neighborhood, house type, etc). The problem is that the topojson file is 121 MB so it takes a long time to load, and when I try to zoom it reloads the entire map which takes a long time.

I want to make it so the json file only draws the necessary part of the map at a certain zoom level. In other words, when the user is zoomed out far, I want it to render a different, smaller map, and when they zoom in to a certain closer zoom level, it will draw the part of the topojson file that would show on the screen at that point.

I've tried searching and have so far been unable to find how to render only part of the topojson file that is showing and only at a certain zoom level.